# Cross table sum join in postgres

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table

I have this table:

| product | amount | no_of_customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prdct_1 | 100 | 9 |
| Prdct_1 | 200 | 15 |
| Prdct_2 | 50 | 2 |
| Prdct_3 | 40 | 5 |
| Prdct_3 | 80 | 5 |
| Prdct_4 | 10 | 1 |

I want to join this with the below table

| product | no_of_bills |
| --- | --- |
| Prdct_1 | 6 |
| Prdct_1 | 3 |
| Prdct_2 | 4 |
| Prdct_3 | 10 |
| Prdct_3 | 5 |
| Prdct_4 | 2 |

Additionally, I want to add a sum of all categories. So the result should look like this:

| product | amount | no_of_customers | no_of_bills |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prdct_1 | 300 | 24 | 9 |
| Prdct_2 | 50 | 2 | 4 |
| Prdct_3 | 120 | 10 | 15 |
| Prdct_4 | 10 | 1 | 2 |
| Total | 480 | 35 | 30 |

How could I solve it? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have postgres to test immediately, but look at this `sql`, Hope this works for you...

```
SELECT
  product,
  SUM(amount) AS amount,
  SUM(no_of_customers) AS no_of_customers,
  SUM(no_of_bills) AS no_of_bills
FROM (
  SELECT
    product,
    amount,
    no_of_customers
  FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    product,
    0 AS amount,
    0 AS no_of_customers,
    no_of_bills
  FROM table2
) AS t
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY product;
```

The `sql` creates a temporary table `t` from the two tables using `UNION ALL` operation which allows merging tables irrespective of duplicated rows exists or not.
The query then groups the data in the table `t` by the product column wherein all rows with the same product name are grouped together.
For each group, the query sums up the values in columns `amount`, `no_of_customers`, and `no_of_bills columns`, and returns the results in the following order: `product`, `amount`, `no_of_customers`, `no_of_bills`.

That's the logic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the simplest possible solution, but it works for me. I named your tables `products` and `bills`:

```sql
WITH product_summary AS (
  SELECT
    p.product,
    SUM(p.amount) AS amount,
    SUM(p.no_of_customers) AS no_of_customers
  FROM
    products p
  GROUP BY
    p.product
),
bill_summary AS (
  SELECT
    b.product,
    SUM(b.no_of_bills) AS no_of_bills
  FROM
    bills b
  GROUP BY
    b.product
)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    ps.product,
    COALESCE(ps.amount, 0) AS amount,
    COALESCE(ps.no_of_customers, 0) AS no_of_customers,
    COALESCE(bs.no_of_bills, 0) AS no_of_bills
  FROM
    product_summary ps
  FULL JOIN
    bill_summary bs
  ON
    ps.product = bs.product
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Total' AS product,
    SUM(COALESCE(ps.amount, 0)) AS total_amount,
    SUM(COALESCE(ps.no_of_customers, 0)) AS total_customers,
    SUM(COALESCE(bs.no_of_bills, 0)) AS total_bills
  FROM
    product_summary ps
  FULL JOIN
    bill_summary bs
  ON
    ps.product = bs.product
) AS result
ORDER BY
  result.product;
```

I'm using the Common Table Expression (CTE) `product_summary` to calculate the sum of `amount` and `no_of_customers` for each product in the `products` table. The CTE `bill_summary` calculates the sum of `no_of_bills` for each product in the `bills` table. These two results are then combined with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` with `grouping sets` to calculate subtotals and a total, then use join to combine both results from `CTE`s:

```
with product_customers_cte as (
  select COALESCE (product,'Total') as product, sum(amount) as amount, sum(no_of_customers) as no_of_customers
  from product_customers
  group by
    grouping sets (
        (product),
        ()
    )
),
product_bills_cte as (
  select COALESCE (product,'Total') as product, sum(no_of_bills) as no_of_bills
  from product_bills
  group by
    grouping sets (
        (product),
        ()
    )
)
select pc.*, pb.no_of_bills
from product_customers_cte pc
join product_bills_cte pb on pb.product = pc.product
order by product
```

Result :

```
product amount  no_of_customers no_of_bills
Prdct_1 300     24              9
Prdct_2 50      2               4
Prdct_3 120     10              15
Prdct_4 10      1               2
Total   480     37              30
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TFgLsJKo)